# Room : incorrect result of a query with a date condition

Tags: android, android-room

This query is retrieving all the records whatever the date for the pet :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Fooding WHERE pet_Id = :petId AND date(fooding_date) = date(current_timestamp)")
Flowable<List<Fooding>> getDailyFoodingsForPet (Long petId);
```

Converters :

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

@androidx.room.TypeConverter
public static OffsetDateTime toOffsetDateTime(String value) {
   return value == null ? null : OffsetDateTime.parse(value,dtf);
}

@androidx.room.TypeConverter
public static String fromOffsetDateTime(OffsetDateTime value) {
   return value == null ? null : value.format(dtf);
}
```

Entity :

```
public class Fooding implements Parcelable {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Long foodingId;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_Id")
    private Long userId;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pet_Id")
    private Long petId;
    @TypeConverters(DataTypeConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fooding_date")
    private OffsetDateTime foodingDate;
    private Integer quantity;
```

Does anyone have any idea of ​​the problem ?

---

Edit : this query have the same result :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Fooding WHERE pet_Id = :petId AND date(fooding_date) = date('now')")
Flowable<List<Fooding>> getDailyFoodingsForPet (Long petId);
```

Comment: Why are you doing a where on dates but not specifying the date you want? I dont see anywhere where `current_timestamp` is set or even exists

Comment: I want to retrieve all the records of the day, doing this through SQL seems to me to be easier. Doesn't the function `date(current_timestamp)` return the date of the day ?